# Can I use V8's inspector protocol to debug js code that is loaded from a snapshot?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I embed v8 in my server application. Now I want to connect to the server's V8 to send inspect protocol to debug js code. The server side use V8's snapshot tech to get less creating time. However, when I send the inspect protocol, I failed with this error:

> ```
> 2019/03/13 11:23:34 recv: 1, {"id":13,"method":"Debugger.getPossibleBreakpoints","params":{"start":{"scriptId":"7","lineNumber":2,"columnNumber":0},"end":{"scriptId":"7","lineNumber":3,"columnNumber":0},"restrictToFunction":false}}
> worker_dispatch_message 202
> 2019/03/13 11:23:34 send: {"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot retrive script
> ```
>
> context"},"id":13}

Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

V8 developer here. This might be a bug; the team is looking into it.

In the meantime, the easiest workaround is probably to disable the snapshot for debugging.

Comment: Thank you. If you find out the reason, could you let me know as soon as possible? As the time decreases a lot when we use snapshot, we would like to keep this feature. And we have to give the ability of debugging over inspector protocol to the client, so the workaround seems not OK for us.

Comment: You can follow along at crbug.com/v8/9029 (just 'star' the bug to get emails on any updates).